# Android C2DM Registration Id Change Frequency

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-c2dm

I have built and Android app (not in the Market yet) and I am struggling to figure out why C2DM is failing. I am able to register my device, and I get back a registration Id.

I have built a server app that submits the request to google's C2DM server and I get back a 200 response and a message id. (Success). The issue is, my device never gets the messages.

One of the things that surprises me is that if I try to register a device twice within seconds I get back a different registration id. Most likely they use time as a seed.

Is it normal for this registration id to change so frequently? Any clues / advice (I read the guidelines already)?

Cheers...

Note: 
I do not have a sim card and all I use is a corporate WiFi network. My last hope is that maybe port 5228 is closed on my network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that port 5228 was closed on the network I was using.

Answer (score 2):

Google says that C2DM will change anytime. So you have to update your server with the correct registration id for the device. If the id server has doesnt match the one which google sent to your device, it will not be able to deliver the push.

So as a golden rule, "always update the server with the latest c2dm registration id as soon as you get it"

if Google replies with 200, the body should contain an id. if there is an error, there will be  an error in the body. the error codes are given below.

- QuotaExceeded — Too many messages sent by the sender. Retry after a while.
- DeviceQuotaExceeded — Too many messages sent by the sender to a specific device. Retry after a while.
- MissingRegistration — Missing registration_id. Sender should always add the registration_id to the request.
- InvalidRegistration — Bad registration_id. Sender should remove this registration_id.
- MismatchSenderId — The sender_id contained in the registration_id does not match the sender id used to register with the C2DM servers.
- NotRegistered — The user has uninstalled the application or turned off notifications. Sender should stop sending messages to this device and delete the registration_id. The client needs to re-register with the c2dm servers to receive notifications again.
- MessageTooBig — The payload of the message is too big, see the limitations. Reduce the size of the message.
- MissingCollapseKey — Collapse key is required. Include collapse key in the request.

This info is from http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/#testing

Comment: That's what I do. I register. I grab the registration id. I pass it to the server. Then I send a message. Google replies with 200 and a message id but the message never reaches my device.

Answer (score 1):

Yes as Rihan said every time you registered your device you will get a new `registration ID`.and if you are getting  `registration ID` that your c2dm is successfully implemented from google server.Now you have to send this ID to your server .And by using this ID you have send push notification to your device.

Now you will get message in OnReceive() method of C2DReceiver and you have to handle this message(May you give a notification to user)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, the issue was in the app I wasn't sending the right email address used to register for the C2DM messaging. So it kept failing.

So check if you are sending the correct email address as the senders email address when registering for C2DM from the device that is the email address registered with google for push notifications.

Comment: I am sharing a constants file between the client and the server and they are both using the same address. On the device, however, I am signed in with a different id.

Answer (score 0):

Although Rihan is correct. The registration id changes every time. The reason why I was not getting the messages is because the port was locked.

For other googlers, make sure 5228 is open before you go mad...